# Got Build error but program still run perfectly

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, adt

I add some files to assests folder on android project and got problem in desktop project
someone know this?

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Rope-desktop'.
Negative time

Comment: And what are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting eclipse or PC? And try to clean your project.

Comment: I just don't have enough reputation for commenting. And author's question is too unclear. In this case i only can give some general advices.